# Communication between children components: Show / Hide shopping cart using emit from a button in other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I’m working on a shopping cart using vue3 with inertiajs and Laravel and page layout demands to have a main menu with a bag button which on click fires showing and hiding cart event.
So as menu and cart are children component from main page, I guess that the goal is by using communication between components.
I’ve read emit documentation and I can get it working from parent to child and from child to parent, but I can’t achieve the communication between both children components.

I have the following code:

Parent

```
<Cart :isVisible="showCart" @hideCart="showCart = false" />

<script>
export default { 
  data() {
    return {
      showCart: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleCart() {
      this.showCart = !this.showCart    
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Menu

```
<button @click="$emit('toggleCart')"><Icon name="bag" class="w-4" /></button>
```

Cart

```
<template>
<div v-if="isVisible">
    <h3 class="flex justify-between">
        <span class="font-bold">My cart</span>
        <button @click="$emit('toggleCart')" class="text-xl">&times;</button>
   </h3>
  ...html code for cart
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
const props = defineProps(["isVisible", "cart"]);
const emit = defineEmits(["toggleCart"]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$emit` doesn't call a method in the parent, you have to handle the $emitted event yourself, usually by calling a method. So in your parent component you should have:

```
<template>
    <Cart :isVisible="showCart" @toggle-cart="toggleCart"..... />
    <Menu @toggle-cart="toggleCart" ..... />
</template>

<script>
  //...
  methods: {
    toggleCart() {
      this.showCart = !this.showCart    
    },
  //...

</script>
```

The `@toggle-cart=` is referring to the emitted event, the `"toggleCart"` is referring to the method in your parent component, but there's no need for them to have the same name. You could have `@toggle-cart="handleCartToggle"` as long as `handleCartToggle` is your method name.
(Note: The kebab-case `@toggle-cart` instead of `@toggleCart` is how Vue [recommends](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events) you refer to events in the template, to align with HTML attributes. Still use `toggleCart` in the Cart component.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and for your kindly explanation. Applying your suggestion everything works fine. Regards.